# How do I match a word followed by new line then grab the next line up to its new line?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm editing a bunch of SQL files and I need to remove date references in the queries.  However the way the files are written is that logical operators like, OR and AND are on lines by themselves and the rest of the associated argument are on another line.  Like so:

```
OR
   field.lastupdate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 31 DAY))
AND
  *some more code*
```

I want to remove the OR (and it can be an AND too) up to the newline character, in this example, after the second parenthesis.  However I want to leave the rest of the code intact.

I think the regex should be straightforward except how do I ignore the newline after the OR but stop at the following newline?

I should note that some of the date lines I want to remove end with a `";"` which I do not want to remove.

Here's a more complete example that I hope clears things up:

```
OR
        x.is_deleted = 0
OR
        x.lastupd > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 31 DAY))
AND
        (j.active = 1
OR
        j.is_deleted = 0
OR
        j.lastupd > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 31 DAY));
```

So you see I want to keep the first "OR" and it's following line,

delete the second "OR" and the line that follows it.

Keep the "AND" and the line that follows it as well as the following "OR" and it's corresponding line.

And then delete the final "OR" and it's line while leaving the final ";".

Comment: "[...] up to the newline character, in this example, after the second parenthesis", there is no newline after "the second parenthesis". You just want to remove the following line?

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql =~ s/\b(?:OR|AND)[ \t]*[\n\r]+(?=.*DATE).*(?<![;\s])//mg;
```

Removes the `OR` (or `AND`) and the content on the following line (if it contains `DATE`), except the possible ending `;`.

**Note** that such simple regex will not work with your updated example, because there are closing parenthesis on the removed line which belong to other lines.

Example at http://ideone.com/0Lbxp

Answer (score 0):

Well i'm not whether there is only one sentence after sentence having OR/AND.

The idea is to keep track of a flag which will tell you that you came across an OR/AND in the previous sentence.

Probably you can do something like this.

```
open(FPTR, "infilename")
    or die "\nCan't open $filename for reading: $!\n";
open(OUT, ">outfilename")
    or die "\nCan't open $OUT for writing: $!\n";
my $st=0;
while(<FPTR>)
{
if($_ =~ m/OR$/ || $_ =~ m/AND$/) {
    $st=1;
}
elsif($st==1 $$ **match to your sentence**) {
    $st=0; 
    next;#since you want to remove the line followed by line containing OR/AND

}
else {
    print OUT $_;
    #i'm not sure if here also you need to set $st=0;
}

}

close(FPTR);
close(OUT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the simpler solutions are the best. This script will only (re)print lines that do not match the description of the lines you wanted removed. It will print a trailing semi-colon `;` if it finds one. It will preserve the lines as read.

It relies on no lines being empty, and that no wanted lines contain the word DATE_SUB.

**Usage:**

```
$ script.pl input.txt > output.txt
```

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use ARGV::readonly;

while (my $line1 = <>) {
    if ($line1 =~ /^\s*(OR|AND)\s*$/) {
        my $line2 = <>;
        if ($line2 =~ /DATE_SUB/) {
            if ($line2 =~ /;\s*$/) {
                print ";\n";
            }
        } else {
            print $line1, $line2;
        }
    } else {
        print $line1;
    }
}
```